# How to shuffle a pandas dataframe randomly by row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle a pandas dataframe by row instead of column.

I have the following dataframe:

```
   row1    row2    row3
1    3      1       6
2    5      2       7
3    7      3       8 
4    9      4       9
```

And would like to shuffle the df to achieve a random permutation such as:

```
   row1    row2    row3
1    6      3       1
2    3      9       2
3    7      5       8 
4    4      9       7
```

I tried:

```
df1 = df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))
```

however, this permutes only by column and not row.

Comment: Not sure I understand - If its per row, shouldn't the elems in every row stay there, but simply shuffled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the sample method and apply it to axis # 1.
This will shuffle the elements in a row:

```
df = df.sample(frac=1, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

How ever your desired dataframe looks completely randomised, which can be done by shuffling by row and then by column:

```
df = df.sample(frac=1, axis=1).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Edit:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.apply(np.random.permutation, axis=1)
```

Comment: This only shuffles the values in each column and just moves the values to a different position in the dataframe. I want each row to be shuffled so that the sum of each column is not equal to the original sum. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: You are right! I edited my answer!